# Having a hard time formatting code/file

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting

I was improving the edit and contents of [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28563463/2495341), but there was one part that wouldn't stop fighting back. Let me try to reproduce it here:

#### Start of text

3. Then you can open the file and write all the untracked files you want to ignore for good. For example, mine looks like this:

---

```
OS junk files
[Tt]humbs.db
*.DS_Store

#Visual Studio files
*.[Oo]bj
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.[Cc]ache
*.ilk
*.log
*.lib
*.sbr
*.sdf
*.pyc
*.xml
ipch/
obj/
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
[Rr]elease*/
Ankh.NoLoad

#Tooling
_ReSharper*/
*.resharper
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*

#Project files
[Bb]uild/

#Subversion files
.svn

# Office Temp Files
~$*
```

There's a [whole collection of useful .gitignore files by GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28563463/2495341)

#### End of text

I invite you to edit this formatted file, because I couldn't just leave it without that line or some other annoying trick. Code it, uncode it, more space, less space, three tildes and none; and any combination of those... nothing seemed to pleased the formatting god. I simulated the same thing in a GitHub issue just to try it and three tildes worked wonderfully there. So maybe it's a bug.

I just want to have the file (the .gitignore shown in the post) to be formatted as it's showing without having to do tricks with lines or anything like that.

Comment: Didn't find that one out. Still, is a very old question with no solutions, only ugly work arounds to what is clearly a bug. GitHub doesn't have this problem so why should we? Can we deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

1. This is a list item

   ```
   This is some code

   Here's another line of code
   ```

   Here's some text

   ```
   Some more code
   ```
2. And this is another list item

---

Raw:

```
1. This is a list item

        This is some code

        Here's another line of code

   Here's some text

        Some more code

2. And this is another list item
```

Comment: So 2 * 4 spaces of indent. You do that in a text editor and paste it back I assume?

Comment: That, or whatever is the quickest method on your set up. I have a userscript which indents highlighted text when you hit tab instead of changing to the next element.

Comment: That sounds good. Share?

Comment: On my way out at the moment, I'm sure there's something on Stack Apps. If you haven't found anything by the time I get back, I'll upload it and post a link here.

Comment: Much appreciated